# How do I unit-test logic involving CLBeacons?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, core-location, ibeacon

I'd like to run some tests on a view controller involving CLBeacons.  Unfortunately, while CLBeacons are not themselves a private class, all the necessary properties on them are read-only, without any write accessors.

The methods are written in a manner that should help maximize testability, but without the ability to generate the CLBeacons, how do I test my view controller's logic regarding them?

Edit:

To explain the scope of my purpose, I'm experiencing some odd behavior in the app at times.  I want to try and confirm the source of the odd behavior is in a specific area of code by testing various scenarios and confirming that various other related components in my code work correctly.  (E. g. I can test that my data handling works correctly, therefore I'll know it's the animation / layout code that is misbehaving).

Comment: You could [mock](http://ocmock.org/) the beacons, and pass the beacon in when creating your view controller, or simply as an argument to a given method. http://www.objc.io/issue-1/testing-view-controllers.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done this by using [OCMockito](https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito) with XCTest.

```
CLBeacon *mockBeacon = mock([CLBeacon class]);
```

Then I can use this to call the delegate methods on the class that is the CoreLocation delegate. The test might look like this:

```
- (void)testDidRangeOnABeacon
{
    MyLocationDelegate *myDelegate = [[MyLocationDelegate alloc] init];

    CLLocationManager *mockManager = mock([CLLocationManager class]);
    CLBeacon *mockBeacon  = mock([CLBeacon class]);
    CLBeaconRegion *mockRegion  = mock([CLBeaconRegion class]);


    [myDelegate locationManager:mockManager
                didRangeBeacons:@[mockBeacon]
                       inRegion:mockRegion];


    // XCTAsserts...
    XCTAssert([myDelegate.checkSomethingAboutRanging]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot create CLBeacon instances directly, maybe you could refactor your methods to take as parameter a `CustomBeacon`, defined like this:

```
@interface CustomBeacon : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *major;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *minor;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLProximity proximity;
// plus all other fields in CLBeacon..

+ (instancetype) customBeaconWithBeacon:(CLBeacon *) beacon;
- (instancetype) initWithBeacon:(CLBeacon *) beacon;

@end
```

Then you can simply use `[[CustomBeacon customBeaconWithBeacon:realBeacon]` instead of `realBeacon` when you are dealing with `CLBeacon` (after monitoring), and in your test you can instantiate your `CustomBeacon` instances directly.

Not as clean as using CLBeacon, but this is the best I could think of regarding testability.